# Proving that $A$ is a closed set.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-writing, proof-explanation, normed-spaces

The set A is defined as : $A := \left \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^d : \parallel x\parallel_{1}  \leq 1 \right \}$. How can I go about proving  that $A$ is a closed set.

I know that in this case, we are not using the Euclidean norm, because we have $\parallel x\parallel_{1}$ and *not* $\parallel x\parallel_{2}$. 
I know that the intersection of closed sets is  closed.

I also know that a set is open if and only if it's equal to the union of a collection of open balls, so in this example, to show that the set is closed, the above can not hold.

I seem to be lost, on how to prove this problem, could anybody provide a proof for this problem ? Thank You!

Comment: What is the closure of the set?

Comment: You can show that the complement of $A$ is an open set.

Comment: Do you know that the function $f(x)=||x||_1$ is continuous under the $||\cdot||_2$ norm?. To show this you can also use the inequality $||x||_1 \leq \sqrt{d}||x||_2$

Comment: What is the topolgoy are you using on $\mathbb{R}^d$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any norm is $1$-Lipschitz, hence continuous, as it satisfies the triangular inequality:
$$\|x\|=\|x-y+y\|\leqslant\|x-y\|+\|y\|,$$
so that $\|x\|-\|y\|\leqslant\|x-y\|$, by symmetry, one finally gets $|\|x\|-\|y\||\leqslant\|x-y\|.$

Therefore, $A$ is a continuous preimage of a closed set, namely $[0,1]$, and so is closed.

Comment: Is that sufficient enough to prove that problem ?

Comment: Just added how to conclude.

Comment: For any given finite $n$, all norms on $\Bbb R^n$ (or on $\Bbb C^n$) are (topologically) equivalent. That is, all norms on $\Bbb R^n$ (or on $\Bbb C^n$) generate the same topology. Do you want a proof that $\|\cdot \|_1$ and $\|\cdot \|_2$ are equivalent on $\Bbb R^n$ ?

Answer (score 1):

The norm n(x) = ||x||, is a continuous function. A is the
inverse image of the closed set [0,1] by n, hence closed.

Comment: How is your answer different than mine posted $7$ hours earlier? I don't really mind, I am just confused.